# Upgrade from .net 4 to 4.5 breaks Html.Raw call in Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in a c# MVC 3 razor page where I am passing serialized data into a javascript variable for KnockoutJs:

```
    @{   
        var listData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.ListItems);
        var pagerData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Pager);
    }


// additional code

    <script type="text/javascript" >

        var ListData = @(Html.Raw(listData));  // <-- Syntax Error here
        var PagerData = @(Html.Raw(pagerData));  // <-- Syntax Error here

     // additional js code

    </script>
```

After upgrading to VS 2012, I am getting error squiggles after the javascript semi-colons at the end the Html.Raw lines above. The project complies but VS 2012 displays 'Syntax Error' in the Error List for each line. Without the semi-colons the javascript also shows a 'Syntax Error'.

This code worked without issues in the previous version. Is this a bug in the VS 2012 parser and is there a way to avoid the generated errors?

**Edit**
Anyone else seeing this issue? Below is a simplified version with the same issue isolated in a new page. If you add a semi-colon at the end of the ListData line you get a javascript syntax error, without one it is on the next line. Is this a bug in the javascript compiler between VS2010 and VS2012?

```
@{   
    var listData = "test";
    var pagerData = "test2";
}
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var ListData =  @(Html.Raw(listData))
        var PagerData =  @(Html.Raw(pagerData))
    </script>
```

Comment: No. At least not on the machine this project is on.

Comment: I thought it might have been a resharper thing as i moved back to an old version and thought the problem had gone, but it hasnt. Although i only get it on the odd line, not every line.

Comment: You mentioned that the project compiles.  Does the generated HTML look correct, e.g. with well-formed Javascript?  Or does it look like something is being double-encoded or otherwise malformed?

Comment: STILL not fixed in VS2013. connect is the black hole of bugs. i seriously believe that they look at connect for a list of which issues to intentionally leave in the product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add vote on this [connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760339/valid-javascript-razor-syntax-marked-as-syntax-error).  We will address this issue in next version of VS. I have attached your repro code to this bug and added link to this post as another manifestation of the issue.

Comment: Glad to see some movement on this issue. The link above did not work (404) for me even when already signed in to the Connect site. Could you check the link.

Comment: link works for me with my live id.. product is visual studio. title says "Valid javascript/Razor syntax marked as syntax error" by notken_uk

Comment: Thanks. I must not have the correct permissions or something. The URL contains that title but the content is "page not found".

Comment: Can you try submitting new connect issue and let me know the feedback  id? I will resolve your issue as dupe.

Comment: In order to register the bug against Visual Studio, it took me through some other questions and registration. At the end of that process, I was able to access the page above. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you can now access the bug database.

Comment: What is considered the next version of VS? This is still happening in VS2012 and VS2013 with MVC5.

Comment: @crush, This issue is fixed in VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

This issue still exist in Visual Studio 2013 SP 2

To fix this warning message initialize javascript variable first. IMO Visual studio think var as implicitly typed if any var followed by @.

```
        var ListData;
        var PagerData;
        ListData =  @(Html.Raw(listData));
        PagerData =  @(Html.Raw(pagerData));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in VS2012. I still get the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MVC5 and finding the same issue, so I solved it this way, which should work in all versions

```
@Html.Raw("var myData = " +  Json.Encode(this.Model.MyData) + ";" )
```

However, I would use this only in the simplest situations since you lose any intellisense as to VAR type (although it does treat it as a global instance and the compiler doesn't throw a wobbler), so for now I think an initial, empty definition is probably the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same thing happen, but it does so at random.
What I have tried to resolve it is the following:

Make sure you can compile/build/debug in Debug mode, switch to Release mode and attempt to debug/publish from that mode.
Switch back to Debug mode and re-attempt the publish.

Some combination of switching modes does the trick, I just can'y nail down what it is exactly.
Once you get it working, don't close VS ;-)

Let's hope MS gets this fixed in SP1.